# Type Error: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, typeerror

I wrote this codes:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Notepad(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
    def init_ui(self):
        self.yazi_alani = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.temizle = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Temizle")
        self.kaydet = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Kaydet")
        self.dosya_ac = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Dosya Aç")

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        v_box.addWidget(self.yazi_alani)
        v_box.addWidget(self.temizle)
        v_box.addWidget(self.kaydet)
        v_box.addWidget(self.dosya_ac)

        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setWindowTitle("Barış'ın Notepad Programı")
        self.setGeometry(200,200,800,600)
        self.temizle.clicked.connect(self.temizle)
        self.kaydet.clicked.connect(self.kaydet)
        self.dosya_ac.clicked.connect(self.dosya_ac)
        self.show()
    def temizle(self):
        self.yazi_alani.clear()
    def kaydet(self):         
        dosya_ismi = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Dosya Kaydet",os.getenv("HOME"))
        with open (dosya_ismi[0],"w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(self.yazi_alani.toPlainText())

def dosya_ac(self):
    dosya_ismi = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self, "Dosya Aç", os.getenv("HOME"))
    with open(dosya_ismi[0],"r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
        self.yazi_alani.setText(file.read())
```

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

pencere = Notepad()

sys.exit(app.exec())

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/noikp/Desktop/PyQt5 projem.py", line 41, in <module>
    pencere = Pencere()
  File "C:/Users/noikp/Desktop/PyQt5 projem.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.init_ui()
  File "C:/Users/noikp/Desktop/PyQt5 projem.py", line 28, in init_ui
    self.temizle.clicked.connect(self.temizle)
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'
```

How can I solve this error?
It may be good if you answer fast...

pythonerrors
python
error
errors
errorrr
python3-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your buttons or funcions.
You've got here method Notepad.temizle() AND button Notepad.temizle
So when you expect to send a message, instead you send a button, which is typeError
Also I can see the same error with other methods